# Bitrise: two-factor authentication on ios-auto-provision step

Tags: ios, bitrise

Now that Apple requires two-factor authentication step, I'm facing with that problem on Bitrise. I have integrated `ios-auto-provision` step and it requires the verification code to deploy the app on app store connect but this is automatic on server. Does anybody had or solved this problem?

Please enter the 6 digit code: 
Error:
The input stream is exhausted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create another account without 2FA, give it admin permission and use that for your CI. Only the app store account owner needs 2FA.

Comment: The problem is that I have individual developer account purchased and cannot add people in development team.

Comment: But for enrollment as an Organization it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea for individual developer account? @gereon Thanks

Comment: I don't use bitrise myself, but found https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/mandatory-2fa-two-factor-authentication-for-apple-developer-accounts/8108 which looks like it could be helpful.